# Python Rest API call speed

Tags: python, performance, api, rest, http

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to pull data from a REST API online, and dump it into a local db for further processing.

The API is connected to an online invoicing platform, and I am a bit concerned about the speed of the script.

Currently my script opens a connection, builds a list of invoices. for each invoice the script then opens a connection for that specific invoice lines, which gets dumped into another list.

I am currently reading an account containing 9 invoices and a total of 15 invoicelines. This takes me 7,4 seconds to retrieve.

Can anyone help me with my code? perhaps I can speed it up a bit.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from datetime import datetime
token = "b877aff346ec0c7d238c21a6c33929c84b13a110"

def request(accessToken, url):
    link = 'https://api.billysbilling.com/v2/' +str(url)
    headers=  {'X-Access-Token': accessToken}
    data = requests.get(link, headers=headers).json()
    return data

def invoiceLines(token):
    inv = request(accessToken = token, url = "invoices")["invoices"]
    idList = []
    invoiceLinesList = []
    lines = []
    for r in inv:
        if not r["id"] in idList:
            idList.append(r["id"])
            invoiceLinesList.append(request(accessToken = token,
                                    url = str("invoiceLines?invoiceId=") +
                                          str(r["id"]))["invoiceLines"])
    for invoice in invoiceLinesList:
        for line in invoice:
            lines.append(line)
    return [inv, lines]

start = datetime.now()
data = invoiceLines(token)
print "Time spent - " + str(datetime.now()-start)
print "Invoices - " + str(len(data[0]))
print "Invoice lines - " +str(len(data[1]))
```

Thanks
Henrik

Comment: how long does the data take to retrieve from the remote server? if it takes 6.8 of the 7 seconds total, not much option there for improvement. Have a look at timeit http://dabeaz.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/context-manager-for-timing-benchmarks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Requests [session](http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects), which will automatically reuse one connection for multiple requests. For example:

```
class BillingAPI(object):

    def __init__(self, token, root_url='https://api.billysbilling.com/v2/'):
        self._session = requests.Session()
        self._session.headers['X-Access-Token'] = token
        self.root_url = root_url

    def get(self, url_part):
        url = self.root_url + str(url_part)
        return self._session.get(url).json()


def invoiceLines(token):
    api = BillingAPI(token)
    inv = api.get('invoices')['invoices']
    # ...
```

You can also try requesting invoice lines for different invoices in parallel. The [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) extension can help with that. But please be considerate in order to not overload the server.

Other than this, you will probably be limited by the server performance of the API you’re using.

Consider if you can employ a general optimization such as caching. The [CacheControl](https://github.com/ionrock/cachecontrol) library provides an easy HTTP cache for Requests, but it is unlikely that this API supports HTTP caching, so you will need to roll your own.

Comment: Very nice solution Vasiliy, that just cut the time by two thirds, I'll look into requests-futures extension.